# Convert Opportunity object data to Order object data

Tags: opportunity, order

We've inadvertently adopted opportunity objects as what we internally understand as orders, how would I go about converting my opportunities into orders?

Answer (score 3):

You may need to work with Salesforce Customer Support to enable importing creation dates. I remember having to do this when we went live with Salesforce.

If you have not been using the Orders object, I would probably start by recreating any custom fields in your Orders object that you have in your Opportunity Object.

From there, you can use the Salesforce Data Loader tool to export your Opportunities (as well as any child objects).

Then, import the exported Opportunities back in as Orders.

Finally, update the child objects to link to the new Order ID for each corresponding record.

Once you have verified that the data imported and updated correctly, you can go ahead and delete your old "Opportunities".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this app which is available free on appexchange

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5OM8EAN

Comment: Can you post some more information about it?